# Syntax error with asp.net link tag

Tags: asp.net, css

I am trying to load stylesheet dynamically from folder, but currently, it isn't working:

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
     <link  type="text/css" rel="styleSheet"  href="http://www.domain.com/users/'<%= UserNameVar%>'/styleSheet.css" />
</head>
```

`UserNameVar` contains string data.

Edit: This is the output when i upload it to server. but it is not loading

> ```
> <link type="text/css" rel="styleSheet" href="http://www.domain.com/users/&#39;&lt;%= UserNameVar%>&#39;/styleSheet.css" /></head>
> ```

Comment: How is it not working?

Comment: Hello Simon, i edit the post with output of page on server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put all `href` value in `<%=` and `%>`

Try this:

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
     <link  type="text/css" rel="styleSheet"  href=<%= "http://www.domain.com/users/" + UserNameVar + "/styleSheet.css />" %>     
</head>
```